# Having android.system.GaiException in Apollo Android GraphQL

Tags: android, graphql

I am using [Apollo GraphQL Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin), And recently I have been getting many crashes in `Android vitals` in the Google play console.

[image: Google play console stats]

Here is my current config for `ApolloClient`.

```
ApolloClient.Builder()
                .serverUrl(SERVER_URL)
                .build()
```

Log from google play console

```
Exception : android.system.GaiException android_getaddrinfo failed
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3921)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4078)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2423)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:334)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8333)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:582)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1065)
Caused by io.dHWJSxa.ba: Failed to execute GraphQL http network request
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.DefaultHttpEngine.execute (DefaultHttpEngine.java:12)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$EngineInterceptor.intercept (HttpNetworkTransport.java:2)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.DefaultHttpInterceptorChain.proceed (DefaultHttpInterceptorChain.java)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.api.http.HttpResponse.getHeaders (HttpResponse.java)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.DefaultHttpInterceptorChain.proceed (DefaultHttpInterceptorChain.java)
  at com.w3saver.typography.api.RequestInterceptor.intercept (RequestInterceptor.java:10)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.DefaultHttpInterceptorChain.proceed (DefaultHttpInterceptorChain.java:6)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invokeSuspend (HttpNetworkTransport.java:6)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke (HttpNetworkTransport.java:2)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely (SafeFlow.java:3)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect (AbstractFlow.java:3)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperatorImpl.flowCollect (ChannelFlowOperatorImpl.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collect$suspendImpl (ChannelFlowOperator.java:1)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ReduceKt.single (FlowKt__ReduceKt.java:1)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.single (FlowKt.java:1)
  at com.apollographql.apollo3.ApolloCall.execute (ApolloCall.java:25)
  at com.w3saver.typography.UserInitialPingQuery$Data.getGetUser (UserInitialPingQuery.java)
  at com.xxx.xxx.HomeActivity$fetchUseCaseRequestAndStoreInitialData$1$1.invokeSuspend (HomeActivity.java)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run (LimitedDispatcher.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run (TaskImpl.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely (CoroutineScheduler.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask (CoroutineScheduler.java:5)
Caused by java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "***app.com": No address associated with hostname
  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName (Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr (Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:1152)
  at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup (Dns.java)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress (RouteSelector.java:30)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection (ExchangeFinder.java:30)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection (ExchangeFinder.java:30)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find (ExchangeFinder.java:12)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp (RealCall.java:12)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:12)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:3)
  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:27)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:3)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:28)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:3)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:26)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:3)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.java:10)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute (RealCall.java:7)
Caused by android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
  at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo (Linux.java)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo (ForwardingOs.java:133)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo (BlockGuardOs.java:222)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo (ForwardingOs.java:133)
  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName (Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
```

I cannot reproduce it on my device but 8% of my users are affected by this exception.

network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"/>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.14</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```